# Load View again by passing updated parameter to the same Controller MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view, controller

I want to load the same view again by passing updated parameter from text input on the link click. I tried to use something like `<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {id = "txtCount".value }).`  Not sure if there is even a way to do this. I know I could use partial but I want to reload the whole page with updated parameter. Thanks in advance for any help.

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

View

```
@model int
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input id="txtCount" value="1" />
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 5 @*// get value from txtCount*@ })">Update</a>
        for (int i = 0; i < Model; i++)
        {
            <div>@i </div> 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">Go!</a>
```

and binding with jquery

```
$("#mylink").click(function(){
document.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Controller/Action")' + $("#mytxt").val();
return false;
});
```

Obviously with the proper validations if the textbox is empty and all that stuff.

You cannot add the id value to the `@Url.Action` because it is processed before on the server side, before the page is rendered

Comment: Worked. Thanks! I do have proper validation to the field.